# Python - ValueError: unconverted data remains: 09

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

i'm working on two csv files that contain date column, the first csv file worked fine with my codes but i got error on the second file showing as " ValueError: unconverted data remains: 09".

see below for my codes and screenshots, can anyone help me??

codes:

```
with open(source_csv,newline="") as csvfile:

  csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

  next(csvreader, None)  # skip the headers

  for row in csvreader:

    dictList.append([datetime.strptime(row[0],'%b-%d').strftime('%m%d%Y'),row[1], row[0]])
    mmyy = row[0].split("-")
    month.append(str(mmyy[0]))
    total += int(row[1])
```

error:
[image]

csv file:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the print of `row[0]`?

Comment: row[0]:  Oct-12
Nov-12
Dec-12
Jan-13
Feb-13
Mar-13
Apr-13
May-13
Jun-13
Jul-13
Aug-13
Sep-13
Oct-13
Nov-13
Dec-13
Jan-14
Feb-14
Mar-14
Apr-14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `09` represents the year and not the month.

```
import datetime
s = "Jan-09"
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%b-%y').strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
```

**Output:**

```
01-01-2009
```

Comment: i changed it to datetime.strptime(row[0], '%b-%y').strftime('%m-%d-%Y'), but i'm still getting the same error message of ValueError: unconverted data remains: 09

Comment: row[0] and year 2009 are causing the error and they are: Jan-2009
Feb-2009
Mar-2009
Apr-2009
May-2009
Jun-2009
Jul-2009
Aug-2009
Sep-2009
Oct-2009
Nov-2009
Dec-2009

Comment: i solved it, this is because my two csv files have two different date format. The 1st file has date format as "Dec-13", but the 2nd file has date format as "Dec-2009". so i have to switch between '%b-%y' or '%b-%Y'